# How to display a view depending on a condition inside another condition react native?

Tags: react-native

I want to display a marker if the points is greater than or equal than the cost of the marker. If it is lower than that, it should not render on the view. The markers is in array and the cost is called by `marker.cost`. `points` is a state variable. `this.state.points >= marker.cost` won't work because marker.cost is inside an array.

```
class SupporterMapScreen extends Component<{}> {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      points: 0,
      beaconMarkers: [
        {
          coordinate: {latitude: 14.554180, longitude: 121.044099},
          key: 0,
          cost: 0,
        },
        {
          coordinate: {latitude: 14.552591, longitude: 121.047822},
          key: 1,
          cost: 10,
        },
        {
          coordinate: {latitude: 14.554140, longitude: 121.047201},
          key: 2,
          cost: 20,
        },
      ],
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView
          style = {styles.map}
          initialRegion = {{
            latitude: 14.554180,
            longitude: 121.044099,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
          }}>

          { this.state.beaconMarkers.map(marker => (
            <MapView.Marker
              key={marker.key}
              coordinate={marker.coordinate}
              pinColor='#50FF2E'
              onPress={ () => Alert.alert(
                'Buy Beacon?',
                'It costs ' + marker.cost + ' points in order to buy beacon.',
                [
                  {text: 'No'},
                  {text: 'Yes', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed')},
                ],
                { cancelable: false }
              )}/>
          ))}

        </MapView>
        <View style = {styles.pointsBar}>
          <Text style = {styles.points}>POINTS: {this.state.points}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Possibly you can render Markers according to your Conditions

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.state.beaconMarkers.map(item => {
          if (item.cost == 0) {
            return (
              <View>
                <Text>Equal To Zero </Text>
              </View>
            );
          } else if (item.cost === 10) {
            return (
              <View>
                <Text>Equal To Ten </Text>
              </View>
            );
          }
        })}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```